# Assign a taxonomy term to a view instance

Tags: drupal, view, taxonomy

Is there an easily managed way we can assign a specific taxonomy term to a specific instance of a view?

We're using the callouts module for Drupal, and it works great for nodes/pages we have in our site. But we have a handful of Views that are displaying as a page, but we cannot assign a specific taxonomy term to a specific instance of that view.

The view itself is pulling in lists of nodes based off of a taxonomy argument:

[Example](http://fwmuseum.org/omni-imax-now-showing) On the bottom left, we have some callouts, but they're shown randomly because we can’t assign a term to that page to show specific callouts.

There's 7-8 of these pages, and they all use the same View, but just passing different data through the argument. we've tried assigning the callouts we want to the taxonomy that is used to create the view, but that didn't work either.

Without changing the view output (for example, from a page to a block), how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could assign a taxonomy term to a view, I think it would not help in this case. Blocks are not aware of their context at the time they are rendered, so they have to look at the url to retrieve information about the node that's being displayed. The block checks if the page displays a node; if so the node data is loaded. The callouts module also works like that, as is explained on the module page. Since a view is not a node, the block will not render. To make this work, you would have to alter the callouts module I'm afraid.

Comment: I see what you are seeing, I missed then when reading about the callouts module. And in the could sure enough, it is look up the node id and then getting the taxonomy from there. This might be enough information to get is going on modifying the callout module to work dynamically on pages generated by views also.

Thanks